# Guzzle add api key to url

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I'm working with an RESTful API and I want to get all of its data. So far so good, but I want it to be more secure. I don't want to give the API token straight into the url. I want to use guzzel's auth function, but it won't work.

Example: The base url is `https://example-api-site.com`and I want to get further information, so I go to the site `/location.name?lang=en&input=someLocation&authKey=` instead of using here the authKey ( which works ) I want to use the auth function

Code:

```
$authKey = 'authKey123'; 
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://example-api-site.com']);
$response = $client->request('GET',"/location.name?lang=en&input=someLocation&authKey=",[
    'auth' => [$authKey, null]    
]);
echo $body = $response->getBody();
```

The output of the echo is "invalid auth key:"

I appreciate every comment!

Comment: It depends on how the API handle auth. If the docs told you to put `authKey` as URL params, then you have to do it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Yes it is a parameter. If I click on one of those links they add this line `&authKey=`. So there is no secure option for this?

Comment: This really depends on the API provider, since you don't own the auth, you can't do what you want if they are using this kind of auth you can't do otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You may are looking for raw Authorization header:

```
$response = $client->get('YOUR_ENDPOINT', [
    'Authorization' => [
        'Basic ' . base64_encode('someone@gmail.com:password')
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Would you mind using this on my example? Because my version of this didn't work either

Comment: can you give more info about your api doc?

Answer (score 0):

`'auth'` option is for Basic Authentication, it's not the same as GET-parameter. So if the API accepts only GET-parameter, you are stuck with it.

BTW, security by obscurity is not a real security. You are using HTTPS already, so I don't see any reasons to worry.